# Why can't I keep some variables and rename variable - in place - in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take a dataframe [sample]:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'VAR1': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
                       'VAR2': ['A0', 'AX', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                       'VAR3': ['A0', 'AX', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                       'VAR4': ['A0', 'AX', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})
```

and trying to keep only some columns and rename a column "in place" as:

```
sample[['VAR1','VAR2','VAR3']].rename(columns={'VAR1': 'NEW_VAR'}, inplace = True)
```

with no luck.

However, when I assign a new dataframe without the inplace option, it works as:

```
sample_short=sample[['VAR1','VAR2','VAR3']].rename(columns={'VAR1': 'NEW_VAR'})
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `sample[['VAR1','VAR2','VAR3']]` is a new object. You're calling `.rename` on *that* object, not your original DataFrame. That new object now has no name bound to it, and is dereferenced by Python. Also, I would suggest avoiding the use of `inplace`.

Answer (score 1):

When `inplace=True` is passed, the data is renamed in place (it returns `None`). So basically, you are doing a copy of a dataframe and then performing a method that returns `None`, that's why it's not working.

You should use:

```
sample_short = sample[['VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR3']].rename(columns={'VAR1': 'NEW_VAR'})
```

or

```
sample_short = sample[['VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR3']]
sample_short.rename(columns={'VAR1': 'NEW_VAR'}, inplace=True)
```